# MATLAB simulation

Tags: matlab

How to find a random node from a matrix which contains all the nodes?

Comment: Make up your mind, are you using C# or MatLab?

Comment: i m using matlab but i was not sure about tag

Comment: Just type "matlab" and it'll be tagged [matlab]...?

Comment: i guess...can someone help me out to simulate the code..?

Comment: You're gonna have to give us *a lot* more details if you want help.

Comment: sure..can i know what all info i need to give?

Comment: Do you have any sample code? What does the matrix look like? What do you mean when you say "node"? What are you simulating? Even though we may know MATLAB programming, we don't know *anything* about the *specific* project you are working on unless you tell us.

Comment: @ram: Explain it like you would explain it to another programmer who is not familiar with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a wild guess here and assume that you want to pick a random (i,j) entry from a MxN matrix A.

Initialize i and j using floor(M*rand(1,1)) and floor(N*rand(1,1)), respectively. Then call A(i,j).

Comment: Here's a condensed version: random_element = A(randi(numel(A)));